# .NET - Wierd response from Google Mirror API

Tags: c#-4.0, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I'm getting the following error when I try to post to the Mirror API using Google's .NET API.

> Message    "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nRequired [400]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Required] Location[ - ] Reason[required] Domain[global]\r\n]\r\n" string

The program I'm writing is loaded as a plugin (.dll) from a parent .Net program. When i run my code as a standalone program, I do not see this error. I was wondering if anyone else might have run into a similar situation or could guide me on what to look at?
[image: Screenshot of local variables]

The code I'm using is taken from Googles Mirror example code:

```
        public static TimelineItem InsertTimelineItem(
        String text, String contentType, Stream attachment,
        String notificationLevel)
    {
        TimelineItem timelineItem = new TimelineItem();

        timelineItem.Title = text;
        timelineItem.Text = text;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationLevel))
        {
            timelineItem.Notification = new NotificationConfig()
            {
                Level = notificationLevel
            };
        }
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) && attachment != null)
            {
                // Insert both metadata and media.
                TimelineResource.InsertMediaUpload request = mirrorService.Timeline.Insert(
                    timelineItem, attachment, contentType);
                request.Upload();
                return request.ResponseBody;
            }
            else
            {

                 HttpRequestMessage req=  mirrorService.Timeline.Insert(timelineItem).CreateRequest();
                 string content = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                 bool? pretty=mirrorService.Timeline.Insert(timelineItem).PrettyPrint;
                  // Insert both metadata and media.
                 return mirrorService.Timeline.Insert(timelineItem).Execute();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The exception is fired at the final "return mirrorService.Timeline.Insert" statement.

Comment: Provide your code. If you have an issue with your code, how do you expect us to help you without it?

Comment: sorry about that. Updated question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recompiled the Google Mirror API to use a different version of Newtonsoft.JSON . This has solved the issue. 
The parent program was using a different version of Newtonsoft.JSON, so recompiling the code targeting this version has fixed the issue.

The source code for Google.Apis.Mirror.v1 can be downloaded from https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/download/library/mirror/v1/csharp